# NelmioApiDocBundle hide list of choices

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle

I'm using Symfony2, FOSRestBundle and NelApiDoc to create Rest services.
Documentation created by NelMioApiDoc I have a field that is defined as a choice and extracts all the records in the database. How can I tell NelMioApiDoc to hide values retrieved from database?

Thanks for the answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is your answer, once it is merged:
https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioApiDocBundle/pull/543